# Handling dragging files from Finder into a limited-index NSTableView

Tags: cocoa, drag-and-drop, nstableview

I have an existing NSTableView set up to accept filename dragging from finder. I need to limit the TableView to 10 entries max.

If a user drags in more files than the available slots, should I accept the drop and skim off any excess files, or should I reject the drop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say, fill the remaining slots but reject the drop. Return YES from `-validateDrop:...` but NO from `-acceptDrop:...`.

That way, there will be some indication to the user that not all entries were added, but you'll helpfully add the items which can be added.